# Switch class results dynamically

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to write a code where I could run a function based on it's previous variables.  I don't know how to explain any better but a sample will do. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<?php
$agric = new Agriculture;
$newplant = $agric-> setClass('plant');
$newanimal = $agric->setClass('animal'); 

$agric->getAll(); // returns null

$newplant->setProperties($plant1_data); //uses plant
$newanimal->setProperties($animal1_data); // uses animal

$newplant->setProperties($plant2_data); //uses plant
$newanimal->setProperties($animal2_data); // uses animal

$newplant->getAll(); // returns all plants array
$newanimal->getAll(); // returns all animals array

$agric->getAll(); // returns both plants array and animals 
?>
```

So,  In one form,  the new variables calls the setClass in order to work and everytime it is is called they use their setClass method to know which type of argument they should use to run their code. I know I could do this differently but I seem to love this approach.  Any help will do. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to store data in a static variable, or reference to the data

Comment: I don't think I get you right @George.

Comment: The problem is that since The setClass('animal') was called last, the setClass('plant') is being ignored and even the $newplant->setProperties uses setClass('animal') instead of setClass('plant')

Comment: Of course, because you are not creating objects. Just post code for the Agriculture class

Comment: Okay, Yes you're right.  So,  how to I go about that.

Comment: You should share the agriculture class also

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your example to work, the method setClass from Agriculture must work like a factory: it instantiates a class based on the parameter and returns the object.

Agriculture class must also keep all the objects instantiated inside setClass method in its own internal array, so when getAll method is called, it iterates through each object and executes their own getAll methods.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, but there is no other way in PHP. If setClass() returns the same instance with $this, it will return a reference to the object, and $newplant and $newanimal will be identical. The function setClass() must return new objects for this scenario to work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @everyone..  I finally got the answer to that.  So the reason why I'm giving it to @Dragos is because phone factory seems to be the best approach to it.  So,  all I did was to create two classes.  One is Agriculture which has a method to get the properties of what was called using "getAll()" and the Other is HandleAgric which also has "getAll()".  The HandleAgric has its own setClass which is static and every time it is called,  it instantiates a new Agriculture with its default parameter.  So, Both Classes will have setClass() and getAll() as method.  Something like this

```
<?php
class HandleAgric{
    private static $Agriculture;

    public function __construct(){
        self::setClass();
     }

    function __call($method,$args){  
        $self = new self;
        if(method_exists($self::$Agriculture, $method)){
        $call = call_user_func(array($self::$Agriculture, $method));
        return $call;      
    }
    return trigger_error("Error Found!!! Aborting");
    }

    public static function setClass($class=null){
        self::$Agriculture = new Agriculture;
        $call = self::$Agriculture->setClass($class);
        return $call; 
    }
}


    //Example of usage

    $Agric  = new HandleAgric();
    $Plant  = $Agric::setClass("plant");
    $Animal = $Agric::setClass("animal"); 

    $Plant->setProperties($arrayList);   
    $Animal->setProperties($arrayList);

    @ $Plant->getAll() //return plants properties in array;

    @ $Animal->getAll() //return Animal properties in array;

    @ $Agric->getAll() //return Agric (both plant and animal) properties in array;

?>
```

I believe this to be much better.